# About Numpy's structured arrays

Tags: python, numpy, structured-array

To define structured arrays,we can use tuple argument. 
For example:

```
>>> x = np.zeros(3, dtype=('i4',[('r','u1'), ('g','u1'), ('b','u1'), ('a','u1')]))
>>> x
array([0, 0, 0])
>>> x['r']
array([0, 0, 0], dtype=uint8)
```

I can't understand, why is x `array([0,0,0])`? Why is x['r'] `array([0,0,0])` either?

Comment: maybe you should simply try `np.zeros(3, dtype=[('r','u1'), ('g','u1'), ('b','u1'), ('a','u1')])` for RGB channels

Comment: Is the `i4` outside of the [] intentional?  It's creating a rarely seen dual mapping.  Each element can seen as an 4 bypte int, or as a 4 field record.

Answer (score 0):

This example appears to be copied from the `(base_dtype, new_dtype)` paragraph of the `dtypes` documentation page. https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.dtypes.html

```
32-bit integer, containing fields r, g, b, a that interpret the 4 bytes in the integer as four unsigned integers:

>>>>>> dt = np.dtype(('i4', [('r','u1'),('g','u1'),('b','u1'),('a','u1')]))
```

It's creating a rarely seen dual mapping.  Each element can seen as an 4 bypte int, or as a 4 field record.